# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. BitShuva

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-radio

Hi I've downloaded some source code and I'm having some major issues with it straight out of the box. I've not been able to get an answer from the developer and I've not seen anyone else ask this question, but I've looked and looked and looked and I've no idea what's going wrong.

I keep getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 157:            // Expected ID is standard Raven ID: "songs/4321"
Line 158:            const string expectedIdPrefix = "songs/";
Line 159:            if (song.Id.StartsWith(expectedIdPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
Line 160:            {
Line 161:                throw new ArgumentException("ID wasn't in the expected format.");
```

Visual Studio highlights this bit of code. (denoted by ** **)

```
using (var session = Get.A<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession())
        {
            var songFiles = Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/content/sample/music"), "*.mp3")
                .Select(f => new
                {
                    Song = new Song(Path.GetFileName(f)),
                    FilePath = f
                })
                .ToArray();

                songFiles.ForEach(async f => **await f.Song.UploadMp3ToCdn(f.FilePath));**

            if (!session.Query<Song>().Any())
            {
                songFiles.ForEach(s => session.Store(s));

                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: is your query var songFiles = ... is returning something. Have you verified songFiles is not null?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inspecting `songFiles` within the debugger? The error seems to suggest that either `f.Song` or `f.FilePath` is null/uninitialised.

Comment: It's a `NullReferenceException`, so its likely that `f` itself is null.

Comment: Fair point, I was looking at the `UploadMp3ToCdn`, and was potentially drunk =D

Comment: There are some nulls but the entire f.song isn't null, and neither is f.FilePath.

I would like to reiterate that this is NOT MY CODE, this is a straight from download source code that is suppose to work out of the box with sample music and everything. The Source Code is from BitShuva.

Comment: Perhaps place a breakpoint in the UploadMp3ToCdn method and see if an object is failing initialisation in there?

Comment: @user1760784, we know its not your code.  Even if it was, there's no need to be defensive.

Comment: Not being Defensive actually, just stating a fact. It's not my code so I'm not entirely sure what all the parts are suppose to be doing.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue, it's trying to upload music to the CDN specified in the web.config file, and it's looking for the ID of the song. The ID must be generated by Raven database first, and it's trying to pull the ID prior.

Issue Fixed.